# What airport fees are charged to airlines in the case of operations following an unscheduled landing?

Tags: airline-operations, airport

A plane may need make an unscheduled landing in the case of a diversion due to mechanical difficulties, unexpected weather, a medical emergency or other reasons (this could even be at an airport with which the operator has no prior agreements).

Airport operators agree various fees with the airlines that use them for their scheduled operations:

- runway/landing fees
- fees for stairs, buses to the terminal building, or airbridges
- passenger charges, should the passengers need to disembark
- parking fees
- ...amongst others

Which of these charges are typically levied in the case of an unscheduled landing caused by unforeseen circumstances?

Answer (score 4):

A while back I was on my way to Frankfurt on Delta for a business meeting when a frail passenger (who quite honestly should have never been allowed to board in the first place) passed away before getting to the midpoint of the trip. The captain turned the aircraft around and landed at Gander International in Canada, where we spent the night before continuing on our way.

Because I've seen this in the news once in a while, I decided to check the airport's web site to see what is their fee structure. Lo and behold, [they publish a comprehensive list of fees that covers everything related to an occurrence of this type](http://www.ganderairport.com/about-giaa/airport-fees/).

The fee structure even covers "air rage" incidents under the category of "Emergency" and is charged at so-many-dollars per 1000 kg!

> **Emergency**
>   Including medical, mechanical, air rage, etc.
>   $12.57 per 1000kg

Comment: That is simply the land fee, it doesn't say if other fees the OP asked about are chargeable.

Comment: The [document that Juan Jimenez referred to](http://www.ganderairport.com/about-giaa/airport-fees/) mentions landing fees, terminal fees, and parking fees. The fact that it mentions a special rate for emergency landings suggests that the other fees (parking etc) apply whatever the case.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Indeed they do, I never suggested otherwise, but my answer is directed towards the situation presented in the question, and not all operational situations.